# Groovy trait asks me to implement all of it's super class's methods while it have been implemented on another interface

Tags: java, groovy, interface, traits

I have an interface `A` (in java)

```
public interface A {
    File getFile();
    void delete();
    void delete0();
}
```

And an interface `B` extends `A` (in java)

```
public interface B extends A {
    default void delete() {
        this.getFile().delete();
    }
}
```

And an interface `C` that also extends `A` (in java)

```
public interface C extends A {
    default void delete0() {
        this.getFile().delete();
    }
}
```

And I have a trait `D` that implements `A` (in groovy)

```
public trait D implements A {
    private File file;
    public File getFile() {
        return this.file;
    }
}
```

finally, I have a class `E` that implements `B`, `C`, `D` (in groovy)

```
public class E implements B, C, D {
}
```

When compiling, the compiler complains about class `E` that it does not implement the method `delete0()`

Comment: your last class name is D, it should be E

Comment: What groovy version is this? I am confused about the `default` in the `trait D`

Comment: sorry, I wrote 'D' instead of 'E', and also sorry for 'default' modifier I meant 'public'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works with Groovy 3.0.1, I assume you are using an earlier version with a bug.